# Destination for (half-) day hike near Kraków, Poland in late autumn/early winter

Tags: hiking, poland

At the end of this month, I will be spending some days in Kraków, Poland. I might have a half or a full day available and apart from exploring the city, I'd like to do some hiking in the close surroundings. It will be only a short hike: one day at most, probably just a few hours.

Can anyone recommend a nice destination for a half-day hike close to Kraków? I will be dependent on public transportation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Krakow is amazingly beautiful and interesting town, so you may end up spending all your time in the town itself, but there are some great opportunities for hiking nearby. 
There are several websites about Krakow that you can look at.  [This one](http://www.cracow-life.com/poland/krakow-day-trips) lists some ideas for day trips.  The [Ojcow](http://www.staff.amu.edu.pl/~zbzw/ph/pnp/ojco.htm) national park is just north of Krakow, apparently it is possible to get there by bus. If you are willing to travel a bit further, about 70km south of Krakow are the Beskidy mountains, with [Gorczanski](http://www.staff.amu.edu.pl/~zbzw/ph/pnp/gorc.htm) and [Babigorski](http://www.staff.amu.edu.pl/~zbzw/ph/pnp/babi.htm) national parks.  All of those are definitely worth seeing, and offer plenty of hiking opportunities.

It takes about hour and 30 minutes to get from Krakow Main station to Sucha Beskidzka, which is sort of a gateway into that part of Beskidy mountains.  There is a very nice [brochure](http://www.powiatsuski.pl/download/zalaczniki/wydzialy/wp/szlaki-turystyczne/EN_Szlaki_PDBG.pdf)(pdf) describing some hiking opportunities in the region.

Comment: I ended up visiting Ojców, which is indeed nice (although not entirely what I would personally call national park material).